# ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON does not work on real device

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android app to auto-answer incoming calls.
I am using a receiver, and trying to send ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON event when the phone rings.

It all works great on the emulator -
When the phone rings it actually answers the call automatically.

But when I'm trying it on the device it-self it just does not work (HTC Legend).

This is the code:

```
// trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);               
buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown , "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

// trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);               
buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

And this is the receiver code in the XML file:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneOutgoingCallReceiver" android:enabled="true">
  <intent-filter android:priority="0">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" /> 
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".PhoneIncomingCallReceiver" android:enabled="true">
  <intent-filter android:priority="0">
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" /> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>`
```

Anyone know why it does not work on the real device?  What is different?

Answer (score 1):

Please call this method. It is working in my htc wildfire s.

```
public static void answerPhoneHeadsethook(Context context) {

    try {
        Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(
                KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown,
                "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
        buttonDown = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error First Try: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        // froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
        Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(
                KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,
                "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
        buttonUp = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(" **** Error in Second Try: ", "" + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error Second Try: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        headSetUnPluggedintent
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
        headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 1); // 0 = unplugged 1 =
                                                        // Headset with
                                                        // microphone 2 =
                                                        // Headset without
                                                        // microphone
        headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
        // TODO: Should we require a permission?
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);
        headSetUnPluggedintent = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(" **** Error in Third Try: ", "" + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error Third Try: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Second Time call for HTC Mobile

    try {
        // SettingsClass.logMe(tag, "Simulating headset button");
        Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(
                KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown,
                "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
        buttonDown = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(" **** Error in First Try: ", "" + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error First Try: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        // froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
        Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(
                KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,
                "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
        buttonUp = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(" **** Error in Second Try: ", "" + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error Second Try: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        headSetUnPluggedintent
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
        headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 0); // 0 = unplugged 1 = Headset with microphone 2 = Headset without microphone
        headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
        // TODO: Should we require a permission?
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);
        headSetUnPluggedintent = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(" **** Error in Third Try: ", "" + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error Third Try: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```